# Introduction page for website that fades away after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using JSFiddle I created code that has text appear word by word then fade away shortly after the entire sentence is displayed. I am trying to incorporate this into my website but am unsure of how to do so. I have found one website that does a "similar" effect as it appears on their page when you first open it up then never reappears until you clear your cookies. The purpose of this code is to display my companies slogan right as somebody enters my site then slowly fade away showing the original website.

Link to the site that has a similar effect
http://benjaminkerensa.com/

My fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/BeSafer/5g1ov2p3/

Here is my javascript

```
$(function () {
var string = "Through education, we can all BeSafer                            ";
var dest = $('#fadeIn');
var c = 0;
var i = setInterval(function () {
    if (c >= string.length) {
        clearInterval(i);
        dest.text(string);
    } else {
        $('<span>').text(string[c]).
        appendTo(dest).hide().fadeIn(3500);
        c += 1;
    }
}, 80);

});

setTimeout(function() {
$('#fadeIn').fadeOut('slow');
}, 6000); // <-- time in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try wrapping the rest of your website in a div and having the display attribute initially set to `none`, then as your code there finishes, just remove the attribute, or set it to your liking and boom, there's your website.

Comment: However, this will run every-time the webpage is reloaded.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot wrap the site in a div as it is built through squarespace. Also I don't want to irritate my viewers multiple times so having it only show once would be preferable. Thank you for your input though!

Comment: No worries, sorry I couldn’t help any more.